# How to save test result as pass and failed in jmeter in csv file

Tags: jmeter

I am new in jmeter , I have created multiple HTTP Request in a single thread group , Now what i am trying is save all the HTTP Request that is http request with **response code 200** in csv file as TestCase pass and http request with **response code other than 200** as failed. As I want to execute each and every HTTP request one by one and store result in csv file

here is my beanshell PostProcessor

import java.io.*;
                import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

```
            File f=new File("E:\\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\\bin\\JmeterProResult\\testResult.csv");
            FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f);
            BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);
            var rc = prev.getResponseCode();
            if(rc.equals("200")){
             bw.write("test is passed");
            }
            else{
             bw.write("test is failed");
            }
            bw.close();
            fw.close();
```

which is generating output as show only one result but I run two successful http request

[image]

here is mine jmeter structure-- I want to execute each and every HTTP request

[image]

here my desired output should look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Your approach will work only if you have 1 virtual user, any concurrency will lead to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when 2 threads will be writing the same file resulting in concurrent modification and leading to the data loss
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting so you will need to reconsider your "beanshell" approach in any case

So I would recommend using [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin which allows you to store various request/response details into a file in a "safe" way.

Comment: thanks @Dmitri T can you provide me the solution as I am new in jmeter